# How to get the count of a specific word or character for each row?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with a few hundred rows of testers. There are ten columns ("Passed Q1", "Passed Q2", "Passed Q3", etc.) where a value of "Yes" or "No" is assigned. Many online resources have only given me ways to find the count of a specific word in a given range, but I am trying to get count for each row.

Here is an image of the kind of output that I'm trying to get:

[image]

Comment: What techniques did you find and consider  that wouldn't work for a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a table with many "Yes" and "No". To reproduce this problem, I have made a table like yours:

[image]

To get the total count of "Yes" in the **K2** cell for the first row, type in this formula and hit 'enter':

`=COUNTIF(A2:J2, "Yes")`

where `A2:J2` is the cell range for the first count.

Now drag from the edge of the cell of **K2** all way down to get count of each individual row. There you will have something like this:

[image]

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `=countif()` in the formula in column K

Something like this

[image]

You pass in a cell range, and then the text you want to count instances of.